Variable Indefinida MPDF
Buenas Tengo este mensaje de error en una pagina que había creado y funcionaba perfectamente por 1 año sin ningún problema ahora manda error y la única modificación que le he echo es solo cambiar un logo y unas imágenes.

<?php
require_once '../conexion.php';
$NombreRecibo = $_POST['NombreRecibo'];
$CalleRecibo = $_POST['CalleRecibo'];
$Numero = $_POST['Numero'];
$Sector = $_POST['Sector'];
$NombreRecibo = $_POST['NombreRecibo'];
$Monto = $_POST['Monto'];
$ConceptoRecibo = $_POST['ConceptoRecibo'];
$FechaDia = $_POST['fecha_dia'];
$FechaMes = $_POST['fecha_mes'];
$FechaAnio = $_POST['fecha_anio'];
$Correlativo = $_POST['Correlativo'];
$CantidadRecibo = $_POST['CantidadRecibo'];
$Mes = $_POST['Mes'];

$html.= '
'.$Correlativo.' 
'.$Monto.'
'.$FechaDia.' 
'.$FechaAnio.'
'.$NombreRecibo.'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
'.$CalleRecibo.' 
'.$Numero.' 
'.$Sector.' 
'.$CantidadRecibo.' 
'.$ConceptoRecibo.' 
'.$Mes.'  
';

require_once ('../vendor/autoload.php');
$css = file_get_contents (filename: './css/recibo.css');
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(config: []);
$mpdf->WriteHtml(html: $css, mode: \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->WriteHtml(html: $html, mode: \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);
$Filename = $_POST['NombreRecibo'];
$Nombre="{$Filename}_{$FechaDia} De {$FechaMes} Del {$FechaAnio}_{$Correlativo}.pdf";
$mpdf->Output(name: 'C');

este es el código, no he modificado nada tal cual como esta, yo testeaba que todo estuviera bien cuando generaba el PDF ahora da error

Saludos.  Agrega (en alguna línea) previo a donde tienes actualmente $html.=[....]; la inicialización de la mismas en blanco; es decir $html='';.

Tu título dice que la variable indefinida es MPDF, pero la imagen dice que la variable indefinida es $html. Cuál es el error en realidad?

Alcanzo a ver que tienes el $html.=
El problema puede estar en el uso de $html.=, que espera concatenar contenido previo, pero $html no parece estar inicializada antes.
Cambia $html.= por $html = para evitar errores

Lo intente, pero la información no se imprime , bueno no me corrijo no se muestra la información mandada concadenada dentro de la variable $html que es lo que no entiendo si antes funcionaba correctamente y no he cambiado anda en el codigo

¿Si haces un echo $html, te imprime algo?

haciendo un echo si lo muestra intentare imprimir el PD Haber si no da fallos

Con el echo $html , no genera el PDF

¿Donde tienes montado el servidor? Podrías revisar los logs de apache o de nginx para poder saber que pasa.
/var/log/nginx/error.log
/var/log/apache2/error.log
